# CAGradientLayer added to background but rendered on top

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a background layer using this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,
                                UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
                                UIColor.green.cgColor,
                                UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

When I run the app - the background appears to on top of the labels I have.

However when I check the debug view hierarchy - everything appears properly. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

I tried putting the labels in a separate view and then add the CAGradientLayer to the superview, but it was still drawn on top.

You can check the hierarchy here:

[image]

Comment: A simple way to fix this is to create a UIView and add all your labels to that view. And then add this view as the subview of the view in which you add gradient layer. Make background colour of the new view to clear color

Comment: @AthulSethu I tried your suggestion, but the result was the same. I've added what I did in the original post. No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have you ever checked if it works in iOS 13 or other simulator, or print `sublayers ` to  check the order of these layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Tested & works with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
    // just added to some other test controller
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,
                                UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
                                UIColor.green.cgColor,
                                UIColor.blue.cgColor]

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)  // << here !!
    }
```

Comment: Does not work. I am getting an "extra argument at in call" error on the line when I add it.

Comment: @SaltyLemon Are you sure you used `insertSublayer` as shown? Here is used API `open func insertSublayer(_ layer: CALayer, at idx: UInt32)`

Comment: I was still using `addSublayer` instead `insertSublayer` which is why I was experiencing the issue. After switching as per your suggestion everything now works properly.